# Symbolic Matrix Exponential of Large (500x500) Matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I am trying to build a sort of time propagator matrix. I have a matrix $H$ that is 500x500 and i am trying to evaluate $\exp(-H t)$. I need to find this in a symbolic way because i will need to do $\frac{d}{dt}\langle i|\exp(-H t)|i_o \rangle $ for given vectors $|i \rangle$ and $|i_0 \rangle$. I have done it using the Schur and Jordan decomposition, but i can't do it. My pc either freezes, abort the evaluation or it says it can't perform the evaluation.

I know that the problem is this symbolic $t$ variable since if a give a numerical value to it, Mathematica solves it in a few seconds. But how can i do it for any $t$? Am I asking to much of it? My pc is has **Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8 ** and i am using Mathematica 11.0.1 under Ubuntu. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Do you really need it symbolically for any t?  Can you not just evaluate it for many close-together t and take the derivative numerically?

Comment: Are the matrix $H$ and the vector $i_0$ numerical? If so, why not use NDSolveValue?

Comment: You should consider the limitations that play into these sorts of large symbolic computations. Depending upon how many free parameters you have, you might consider a purely numerical procedure using the suggestions that others have offered. That said, I suggest you investigate if there are any symmetries in your matrix that you can exploit. Why are you trying to evaluate this married exponential? Is H a function of t? If it is indeed a time propagator problem, perhaps you can use the [Magnus Expansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion)?

Comment: My matrix $H$ is independent of t. All it's components are real number in the range [0,1] . I need it for every t because i have to evaluate  $\int_0^{\infty} dt t \frac{d}{dt} <i| \exp(-Ht)|i_o>$.

Due to the form of those vectors, $|i> = {0,0,...1,...0} $ with the $1$ on the $i-th$ component, $<i| \exp(-Ht)|j>$ is the component $ij$-th component of the $\exp(-Ht)$. Is there a way to evaluate just that component and not the hole matrix?

Answer (score 4):

Erm. Isn't $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \exp(- t H) = -H \exp(- t H) = - \exp(- t H)H$? The latter two can be evaluated numerically....

Addendum:

This is more and more becoming clear that this is an XY-question.
From the comments it appears that you seek to compute
$$
 \int_0^\infty t \, \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}  \langle u | \exp(- t H) | v\rangle \, \mathrm{d} t
$$
Provided that $H$ is invertible, integration by parts leads to
$$\begin{aligned}
&
 \int_0^T t \, \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}  \langle u | \exp(- t H) | v\rangle \, \mathrm{d} t
\\
&= \Big[ t \, \langle u | \exp(- t H) | v\rangle \Big]_{t=0}^{t=T} -  \int_0^T   \langle u | \exp(- t H) | v\rangle \, \mathrm{d} t
\\
&= 
\Big[ t \, \langle u | \exp(- t H) | v\rangle \Big]_{t=0}^{t=T} 
+ 
\Big[ \langle u | H^{-1} \exp(- t H) | v\rangle \Big]_{t=0}^{t=T}
\\
&= T \, \langle u | \exp(- T H) | v\rangle 
- 0
+ \langle u | H^{-1} \exp(- T H) | v\rangle - \langle u | H^{-1} | v\rangle.
\end{aligned}
$$
Provided that the real parts of the eigenvalues of $H$ are contained in $[\varepsilon,\infty)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, $\langle u | H^{-1} \exp(- T H) | v\rangle$ converges rapidly to $0$ for $T \to \infty$, so we can apply the limit to obtain
$$
 \int_0^\infty t \, \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}  \langle u | \exp(- t H) | v\rangle \, \mathrm{d} t
=
- \langle u | H^{-1} | v\rangle
.
$$

Comment: My matrix $H$ is independent of t. All it's components are real number in the range [0,1] . I need it for every t because i have to evaluate  $\int_0^{\infty} dt t \frac{d}{dt} <i| \exp(-Ht)|i_o>$.

Due to the form of those vectors, $|i> = {0,0,...1,...0} $ with the $1$ on the $i-th$ component, $<i| \exp(-Ht)|j>$ is the component $ij$-th component of the $\exp(-Ht)$. Is there a way to evaluate just that component and not the hole matrix?

Comment: I am sorry. i write it in a cumbersome way. Let me rewrite it,

$\int_0^{\infty}t*\frac{d}{dt}<u|exp(-t*H)|v> dt$

Comment: I see. I edited the post. ($dtt$ really looked like a typo.)

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that the formula you derive is the partial case of the Laplace transform of matrix exponential $\int_0^\infty e^{-ts}e^{tH}\,dt=(sI-H)^{-1}$. Good connection to Green's functions and resolvents.

Comment: I think your integration by parts output shouldn’t have d/dt inside the integral

Comment: Indeed. Thank you, @Carl.